# Why does this print 8? Simple Python list

Tags: python, list

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
print(list[list[4]])
```

Why does this print 8? I don't understand that particular print statement syntax

Comment: `list[4]` is is `5`. `list[5]` is `8`. Clear?

Comment: Because `list[4]` is the value 5

Comment: List[4] is 5, so it’s list[5]

Comment: Please don't name things `list`, because this will overwrite the builtin `list` function and cause awful confusing errors for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about separating that statement into two separate lines and how it works.

First you have the `list[4]` call which is going to return the item in the list at index 4. That item is the value `5`. Then that value `5` is used to pass into the call `list[5]` which will return the item at index 5 which is `8`.

Example of the same logic:

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

val = list[4]  # val is set to 5
print(list[val]) # Print out item at index 5
# prints out 8
```

Comment: That's the explanation I needed, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Because the inner list, `list[4]`, returns `5`. This is then used as index for the outer list, where at the 5th element (Python starts counting at 0) is an 8.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your print statement that we need to evaluate is:

```
list[4]
```

Which evaluates to '5'

Then we evaluate:

```
list[5]
```

which evaluates to '8'